# Django 1.9 models for testing purpose only

Tags: django-1.9

How to create test-only models that are actually migrated to test database in Django 1.9 with these two conditions?

- migration file is not added to any non-test (application) migration set
- relations are created on the remote model (so it can be examined by `remote_model._meta.get_field('related_name')`)

I've already tried these method:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-fake-model (does not create remote relation)
- https://github.com/django/django/pull/4700/commits/c2fef300224402ebb35c3c20243f06fbb67cddda (needs migration file in application's set of migrations)
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7835#comment:20 (does not work with Django 1.9 due to removed module `django.db.models.loading`)

Thanks a lot for responses!